《Google maps routes API》When doing real-time navigation, why is there no straight-ahead indication for the vehicle's direction of travel?
When I use the Google maps routes  API for real-time navigation, I find that the track points do not have better segmentation step data. As a result, I cannot determine whether the current route is straight. How can I solve this problem?enter image description hereenter image description here
As shown in the track in the figure above, the selected area on the way should be straight, but because the track is not well divided, the instructions for the entire path are the same.
I hope to provide a more fine-grained segmentation interface. I hope to know how the straight-line instructions are given when doing real-time navigation? Which path planning interface is used? The interface I post is the Google maps routes API.
